# Are messages still delivered after deleting a chat or clearing its history?

Tags: telegram

If I send a message and it's confirmed to be send (one tick) and then I clear the chat's history, or delete the chat, will the message still be delivered? (Note that I'm not talking about deleting/editing a particular message after posting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, if you sent it to a user/regular group then once you see one tick it's delivered, and there is nothing you can do to delete the message.

If you sent it to a secret chat/super group/channel then you can delete messages even if it has 2 ticks.

Comment: Thank you. Is there perhaps some reference to the official documentation that explains this? (I couldn't find any.)